# What are the best known lower and upper bounds for the second Chebyshev function $\psi(x)$

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I was reading through Jitsuro Nagura's [proof](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-28/issue-4/On-the-interval-containing-at-least-one-prime-number/10.3792/pja/1195570997.full) that there is always a prime between $x$ and $\frac{6x}{5}$ when $x \ge 25$.

In the paper, he uses the following bounds for the second Chebyshev function $\psi(x)$:

$$1.086x > \psi(x) > 0.916x - 6.954$$

If I apply the better upper bound from [Rosser & Schoenfeld, 1962](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-6/issue-1/Approximate-formulas-for-some-functions-of-prime-numbers/10.1215/ijm/1255631807.full) of:

$$1.03883x > \psi(x)$$

Then Nagura's proof shows that there is always a prime between $x$ and $\frac{8x}{7}$ when $x \ge 34$.

Is this the best upper and lower bound for $\psi(x)$:

$$1.03883x > \psi(x) > 0.916x - 6.954$$

Does anyone know of any results that improve on these bounds?

Thanks,

-Larry

Comment: Under RH there is better bound for $|x - \psi(x)|$. http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1976-30-134/S0025-5718-1976-0457374-X/ Sharper bounds for the Chebyshev functions $ \theta (x)$ and $ \psi (x)$. II 

Comment: Doesn't Nagura give $\psi(x) > 0.916x - 2.318$ ?

Comment: @lhf, Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most recent results on bounds for $\psi(x)$ are from this year:

[Sharper estimates for Chebyshev's functions $\vartheta$ and $ψ$](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.7208), February 2013.

> In this article we present some
>   improved results for Chebyshev's
>   functions $\vartheta$ and $\psi$ using
>   the new zero-free region obtained by
>   H. Kadiri and the first
>   $10^{13}$ zeros of the Riemann zeta
>   function on the critical line calculated by
>   Xavier Gourdon. The methods in the
>   proofs are similar to those of the
>   Rosser-Shoenfeld papers on this
>   subject.